# How to make a time series start at 0 (in hours)

Tags: vb.net

I have a series: x-values in datetime format and y-values are just numbers. I need to make the graph start at 0, and increment in hours. So if my series started at 12pm tuesday and went until 5am thursday, 12pm tuesday would be 0 and 5am thursday would be 41. No clue on how to convert this.

Comment: A downvote with no explanation??

Comment: its better the last question, not to delete it, but to answer it so anyone in the future can use your issue and help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I came up with:

```
dim startDate as integer = DateTime.now
dim startDay as integer = startDate.dayOfYear
dim startHour as integer = startDate.hour
dim startMinute as integer = startDate.minute
dim startSecond as integer = startDate.second
```

For extra precision I also included milliseconds

```
dim startMillisecond as integer = startDate.millisecond
```

When it was time to calculate the time difference in hours:

```
timeDifference = ((thisDay - startDay) * 24) + (thisHour - startHour) + ((thisMinute - startMinute) / 60) + ((thisSecond - startSecond) / 3600) + ((thisMillisecond - startMillisecond) / 3600000)
```

`thisDay`, `thisHour`, `thisMinute`, `thisSecond`, `thisMillisecond` were all calculated the same way as the start variables.

Comment: *The answer I came up with:*. You took my code, made some changes and posted as your solution! Nice. What an ungratefull act.

Comment: Your answer was `(thisDate - startDate).day + thisHour - startHour`. This would only post between the range 0-24. My example had a range of 0-41. As your answer did not include minutes it would also post all values within an hour on the same x-axis value which wasn't desired and IMO didn't make sense. Your ex-posted answer was not complete granted it did have a start to my desired want so thank you for the starting spot.

Comment: My answer was *Dim hoursPassed As Integer = (endDate - startDate) * 24 + hourEnd - hourStart*. You forgot(i am not sure) to see the `* 24` part! And if i rember correctly your question title **is** *How to make a time series start at 0 (in hours)*. Do you see the part that says in **hours**? It doesnt say minutes or seconds or milliseconds. Does it??

Comment: I undelete my answer to see it with your own eyes!

Comment: I did forget the `* 24`. Whoops.